# How to write bold greek letters in math mode of rmarkdown knitting to html?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

How to write bold greek letters in math mode of rmarkdown knitting to html? I have tried

````
---
title: "try bold greek"
author: "test"
date: "6/17/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

\usepackage{bm}

### Test

Test 1:
$\mathbf{\alpha}$

Test 2:
$\bm{\alpha}$

Test 3:
**$\alpha$**

```
which renders no bold fonts at all:
"
Test 1: α

Test 2: \bmα

Test 3: α
"
```

Comment: Sorry for the akward formatting, it seems like ``` of the editor and giving a reprex in rmarkdown do not work well together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$